# Bidning with TextBlock is not Working

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, data-binding, binding

I have my Model as:

```
namespace Forecast.MVVM.WPF.ViewModel
{
    public class ApplicationInfoViewModel
    {
       private string versionNumber;
       public ApplicationInfoViewModel()
        {
          versionNumber = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
        }
       public string VersionNumber
        {
            get { return versionNumber; }
            set { versionNumber = value; }
        }
}
```

And my view I am setting the datContext and getting the values as ;

```
<UserControl .... xmlns:AppInfo="clr-namespace:Forecast.MVVM.WPF.ViewModel" .../>
 <UserControl.Resources>
        <AppInfo:ApplicationInfoViewModel x:Key="forecastVersionInfo"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding VersionNumber}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>
```

But I am unable to see the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1st way :**

Try tro replace `<UserControl.Resources>` by `<UserControl.DataContext>`
... and delete "`x:Key="forecastVersionInfo"`".

**2nd way :**
Or set `DataContext="{StaticResource forecastVersionInfo}"` on your textBlock.

**3rd way :**
According to [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746695.aspx), set the Source property on your textblock binding :

```
Text="{Binding VersionNumber, Source={StaticResource forecastVersionInfo}}"
```

Comment: ,@Tilak, What if I want to achieve this by using .ResourceOnly

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting DataContext

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
   <AppInfo:ApplicationInfoViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

If you want to refer to resource, you can set it on `Grid` or move resource to `App.Resources` and apply `DataContext` as attribute on `UserControl`

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Path={StaticResource forecastVersionInfo}}">
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding VersionNumber}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>
```